# ASP.NET MVC - 301 Redirect - SEO issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, iis-6, http-status-code-301

So I have an ActionName like so:

```
[ActionName("Chicago-Bears")]
public ActionResult ChicagoBears() {
  return View();
}
```

Google has this indexed as: http://www.example.com/Teams/ChicagoBears

I'm stuck using IIS6 and have no access to IIS myself.

Of course now, it has a hyphen in it. So, Google will show a 404 if someone clicks on that link.

How do I setup a 301 redirect in this instance?  I can't create another method called ChicagoBears(), so...

Thanks guys.

Comment: You don't need ChicagoBears, just another method with that ActionName Attribute. Then you can redirect in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This blog I referenced seems to no longer be available so I updated the link to reference the internet archive version.

Check out this blog post for a great solution*: https://web.archive.org/web/20160528185929/http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/04/25/ASPNET-MVC-Legacy-Url-Routing.aspx

Essentially what he is doing is creating a reusable class that can be used for multiple routes, and they just issue a permanent redirect to the specified Action method.

**Note: This is not my blog, but one that I simply came across.*

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with linking to your own blog either.  (as long as it's relevant)

Comment: blog no longer available, redirects to twitter

Comment: @stom Good catch. I updated the link to the Internet Archive cached version.

Answer (score 5):

Create a route for Teams/ChicagoBears that points to an action that gives a permanent redirect.

In Global.asax...

```
routes.MapRoute("ChicagoBearsRedirect",
    "Teams/ChicagoBears",
    new { controller = "Teams", action = "RedirectChicagoBears" }
);
```

In TeamsController...

```
public ActionResult RedirectChicagoBears()
{
    return RedirectToActionPermanent("Chicago-Bears");
}
```

Comment: Gotta be a better way than that.  Every link/route basically changed on the site.  I wonder if I should just wait for Google to reindex as opposed to having this little redirect methods all over the place.

Comment: Yuck. The route can accept Regular Expressions so if all of the routes should have a - in it you can just find the ones that don't and send them all to the same action that will do the redirect. Another possibility is to handle the 404 errors.

Comment: RedirectToActionPermanent is MVC 3. Honestly I don't have it installed yet either. It's a little more difficult to do 301s in MVC 2.

Comment: This was much easier than some of the other options.  Thank you.

Comment: We can have this in separate controller check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16980631/2218697) , hope helps.

Answer (score 3):

The URL Re-Write Module is your friend. Learn it, live it, love it...

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

I used it extensively when I migrated from DasBlog to WordPress. All my old blog URLs are re-directed using 301's to the new ones. Highly recommended.

UPDATE: There are URL re-writers for IIS6. A quick google search turned up:

- http://www.isapirewrite.com/
- http://urlrewriter.net/

(Found via http://forums.iis.net/t/1160436.aspx.)

Comment: There are rewrite engines available for IIS6 such as Ionic ISAPI Rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party on this one, but I wrote **[a blog post about permanent redirects for legacy routes](http://forloop.co.uk/asp.net-mvc-permanent-301-redirects-for-legacy-routes)** that allows this -

```
routes.MapLegacyRoute(
    null, 
    "Teams/ChicagoBears", 
    new { controller = "Teams", action = "ChicagoBears", area="" }
);
```

The `Location` to redirect to is generated using the route values using `Url.Action`, so as long as you have a route in the RouteTable that matches the route values, the 301 redirect will work as intended. In your example, the generated URL should be `http://www.example.com/Teams/Chicago-Bears` when the URL pattern matches `"Teams/ChicagoBears"`.

*I won't repeat the code here as there's quite a bit and it's on the blog*